# Python SOAP to code converter?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, suds

I need to send a `SOAP envelope` that looks exactly like this...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:realops.com:amp:workflow" xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:dst="DST_JC_Sandbox">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:grid-name>GRID01</urn:grid-name>
      <oas:Security>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <oas:UsernameToken>
            <oas:Username>Network</oas:Username>
            <oas:Password>password</oas:Password>
         </oas:UsernameToken>
      </oas:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dst:TrySoap-Request>
         <dst:strInput1>abc</dst:strInput1>
         <dst:strInput2>abc123</dst:strInput2>
      </dst:TrySoap-Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using Python `suds`. But, I'm just not wrapping my head around how to control headers. I have only got some hacked together bits since I'm still trying to discover how to send a successful SOAP call to my internal test host (which does respond to soapUI).

```
from suds.client import *
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
from suds.wsse import *
from suds.xsd.sxbasic import Import
from suds.sax.element import Element    

def main():

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

url = 'http://10.1.1.1:8080/path/name/wsdl?grid-name=GRID01'
client = Client(url, faults=False)
tag_name1 = ('urn', url)
urn = Element('grid-name', ns=tag_name1).setText('GRID01')
client.set_options(soapheaders=urn)
print client.service.TrySoap('abc','123')
```

This yields a SOAP envelop like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Sandbox" xmlns:urn="http://10.1.1.1:8080/path/name/wsdl?grid-name=GRID01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <urn:grid-name>GRID01</urn:grid-name>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:TrySoap-Request>
         <ns1:strInput1>abc</ns1:strInput1>
         <ns1:strInput2>xyz</ns1:strInput2>
      </ns1:TrySoap-Request>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

My extent of understanding how this works is only that the envelope I send has to look exactly like the first sample I posted. This request doesn't work and the server responds with, "DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:"

I know my `python generated header doesn't match`.

**Questions:**

1. Is my URL supposed to show in the header?
2. How do I **nest** the Username and Password inside a **UsernameToken** tag?
3. Did I construct the `urn` Element correctly? Or is there a better way?
4. How do I get the `xmlns:urn="urn:realops.com:amp:workflow"` in the header?
5. Is there a `conversion tool` where I can feed it a formatted envelope and have it spit out the code necessary for Python to form the that envelope?

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker provided me this solution for this test call...

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.wsse import *
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

url = 'http://10.1.1.1:8080/file/path/wsdl?grid-name=GRID01'
client = Client(url)
security = Security()
token = UsernameToken('JoeBob','password')
security.tokens.append(token)
client.set_options(wsse=security)
gridns = ('tns','urn:realops.com:amp:workflow')
grid = Element('grid-name',ns=gridns).setText('GRID01')
client.set_options(soapheaders=grid)
result = client.service.TrySoap('abc','123')
print result
```

This produced this envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:tns="urn:realops.com:amp:workflow" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="Sandbox" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <wsse:Security mustUnderstand="true">
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>JoeBob</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <tns:grid-name>GRID01</tns:grid-name>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:TrySoap-Request>
         <ns1:strInput1>abc</ns1:strInput1>
         <ns1:strInput2>123</ns1:strInput2>
      </ns1:TrySoap-Request>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This works, but I'd like to understand why a little better.  I'm confused about the significance of the tag:Variable format.  I also don't quite follow how the namespace was changed through the Element call.